# Creating several minimum spanning trees with specific requirements

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have an undirected graph that contains several nodes of type A and some nodes of type B. I need to create a graph (not necessarily connected globally) such that each type A node is connected (through any number of edges) to at least one type B node. All edges have weights. I want to create an MST that fulfills this condition, but I cannot think of the best algorithm to do that.

Let me clarify.  If I have one type B node, then all I need to do is just create an MST normally.  But since I have more than one type B node, there may be a more efficient way to create an MST that will not require me to connect all the vertices in the graph.  For example, I may choose to ignore a type B node if it's not the cheapest connection to *any* type A node.  In the end, I may well have a graph that has several disconnected MSTs, not just one.

What is the best algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit your description and/or add an example plse ?
If I understand well, a type A node need to be connected to at least one node (either A or B type, we don't care). But what about type B nodes ?

Comment: @DamienProt The posting already says that: the algorithm can ignore a B node.  All we need is to have every connected graph include at least one B node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through this process:

1. Find the least expensive connection to connect a type A node to a type B node.
2. Change that A-node's label to type B.
3. Repeat until there are no more A nodes.

Note one important property of your problem: any minimal solution must have each A node connected to *exactly* one B node.